# python Iris in linux

Tags: python, macos, module, python-iris

I just started using Iris, (and also Mac OS), and installed other modules using

```
    pip install module_name
```

over the terminal.
I did the same for Iris, but when I try to use:

```
    import iris.plot as iplt
```

an error came up:

```
    ImportError: No module named plot
```

Did 'pip install' do an incomplete job? Am I missing something?
I tried installing Iris from source and due to my lack of experience with unix base installation (I mean, using terminal), I failed and confused.  It has been a frustrating day. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

There is no iris package in the pypi.  If you have iris correctly installed then it should find the plot module irrespective of whether your dependencies are correctly installed or not.

The following gives guidance on installing iris on the Mac OS:

https://github.com/SciTools/installation-recipes/tree/master/osx10.9

Comment: This is very useful webpage. However error did occur again while compiling setup (exactly following the instruction), `src/iris/fileformats/pp_packing/pp_packing.c:21:10: fatal error: 'wgdosstuff.h' file not found ..... error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1` ...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can't import a function as something else, only modules.
If you want to import just plot, do `from iris import plot`

Comment: It still not working with the suggestion, for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd thoroughly recommend installing Iris through Conda (or Anaconda if you already have it).

Once you have conda installed, it should be as simple as doing a:

```
conda install -c rsignell iris
```

We are working on formalising and automating the build process, and once that is complete, it should be a matter of using the "scitools" (maintained by the developers of Iris) channel as such:

```
conda install -c scitools iris
```

(The latter may not work just yet though)

This will work for Linux and Mac (and apparently [Windows](https://github.com/SciTools/iris/issues/1284#issuecomment-53009112)). If this does not work for you, then it is a bug, and is probably best addressed in the Iris google group ([a thread already exists](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scitools-iris/TmqcgaxsGh0/PH7rgnkpZVMJ)).

HTH